# json body generation with serialization

Tags: apex

I am trying to create a json like below:

```
[
  {
    "keys": {
      "TranItmId": "00Q34320001PvpZ"
    },
    "values": {
      "ItemCst": "20.00",
      "ItemNm": "00-01"
    }
  },
  {
    "keys": {
      "TranItmId": "00Q3432000tjvpZ"
    },
    "values": {
      "ItemCst": "10.00",
      "ItemNm": "00-02"
    }
  }
]
```

Using the code provided below by @derek-f ([dynamically create rest json body](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/329681/dynamically-create-rest-json-body))

```
List<TransactionItem__c> myRec = new List<TransactionItem__c>([
            SELECT Id, Name, Item_Cost__c
            FROM TransactionItem__c
    WHERE Transaction__c = 'a015g000tghWFxNAAW'
]);
                                                           
Map<String, Object> dataToSerialize = new Map<String, Object>{
        'values' => new Map<String, Object>{
            'ItemCst' => String.valueOf(myRec.get(0).Item_Cost__c)
        },
        'keys' => new Map<String, Object>{
            'TranItmId' => myRec.get(0).Id
        }
};

String theJSON = JSON.serialize(dataToSerialize);
System.debug('JSON = ' + theJSON);
```

but couldn't seem to get around it... appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observe your JSON it starts with `[`, that means it's a list.

You need to just add your map to a `List`

```
List<TransactionItem__c> myRec = new List<TransactionItem__c>([
        SELECT Id, Name, Item_Cost__c
        FROM TransactionItem__c
        WHERE Transaction__c = 'a015g000tghWFxNAAW'
]);
List<Map<String, Object>> lstMapdataToSerialize = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
for(TransactionItem__c objTransactionItem : myRec){
    Map<String, Object> dataToSerialize = new Map<String, Object>{
            'values' => new Map<String, Object>{
                    'ItemCst' => String.valueOf(objTransactionItem.Item_Cost__c)
            },
            'keys' => new Map<String, Object>{
                    'TranItmId' => objTransactionItem.Id
            }
    };
    lstMapdataToSerialize.add(dataToSerialize);
}


String theJSON = JSON.serialize(lstMapdataToSerialize);
System.debug('JSON = ' + theJSON);
```

Comment: Perfect! Only if one knows - which comes with experience! Thanks for the insight and the code. Much appreciated.

Comment: But there is one problem. It only displayed one record, it has 4 records.

Comment: You need to iterate `myRec` and then create the map. Something like this, Updated my answer